# Typescript: Use inferred type of object for use in Generic

Tags: typescript, design-patterns, alpine.js, definitelytyped

### The Context

I'm trying to use [Alpine.js](https://github.com/alpinejs/alpine) together with TypeScript. For that, I'm using  the community-maintained typings package [@types/alpinejs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/alpinejs) ([GitHub](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/types/alpinejs)) together with the re-useable components design pattern [described here](https://alpinejs.dev/globals/alpine-data). Here is a simple example using the type [`AlpineComponent<T>`](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/alpinejs/index.d.ts#L100):

```
// This is the type for alpine components from definitely typed
import { AlpineComponent } from "alpinejs";

/**
 * I have to declare the T-part of the AlpineComponent<T> beforehand,
 * to be able to use it later. Otherwise, all my custom properties
 * will have the type "any"
 */
type Component = AlpineComponent<{
  foo: string;
  greet: (to: string) => string;
  // The list goes on and on and on in real-world code
}>

export default (): Component => {
  return {
    foo: "foo", // type "string", as defined in the type `Component`
    bar: "bar", // inconveniently has the type "any", since I didn't declare it inside my type `Component`...will have to do it manually... 
    greet(to) {
      return `Hello ${to}!`;
    },
    /**
     * init() is being invoked automatically by Alpine.js when the component is mounted
     */
    async init() {
      console.log(this.greet("World")); // greet correctly has the return type "string"
      await this.$nextTick(); // this is a "magic" method from Alpine.js. It's defined in the type `AlpineComponent`.
    },
  }
}
```

As you can see in the above example, right now I first define my type `Component = AlpineComponent{...}` with all the properties I will be using. And then I have to *type them again* when actually building my component.

### Downsides of my current approach

1. Typing everything twice as I'm doing now is quite cumbersome and feels very conflated.
2. On alt-click on any property, my IDE (VS Code) now always jumps to the *definition* in my custom type `Component` rather then to the *implementation* inside my actual code. But I'm actually always more interested in the implementation instead of the definition.

### The actual Question

Is there a better way to organize this, with less repeated typing of properties? Maybe something like inferring the type of the object returned from my component for the dynamic part of `AlpineComponent<T>`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Someone on GitHub came up with exactly what I was looking for:

https://github.com/alpinejs/alpine/issues/2199#issuecomment-1809892127

Using a helper function that augments the provided function with the Alpine.js internals works like a charm:

`utils.ts`:

```js
import type { AlpineComponent } from 'alpinejs'

export const defineComponent = <P, T>(fn: (params: P) => AlpineComponent<T>) => fn
```

`component.ts`:

```js
import { defineComponent } from '~/utils/define-component'

export default defineComponent(() => ({
  isOpen: false,
  init() {
    this.$watch('isOpen', (value) => {
      this.onIsOpenChange(value)
    })
  },
  onIsOpenChange(value: boolean) {
    console.log('isOpen changed to ', value)
  }
}))
```

Using that I can now both

1. make use of Alpine.js internals without TypeScript errors
2. have the implementation (custom functionality) infered from *inside* the component itself